# Как сделать кастомные ответы? discord.py

Tags: discord, бот, discord.py

Некоторые боты, которые я видел могут удалять ваше сообщение с командой и отвечать в следующем сообщении на несуществующее сообщение. То есть я пишу "/play", бот удаляет моё сообщение и присылает своё. Сообщение выглядит так, как будто это ответ на моё сообщение "использует play", хотя я такое сообщение не писал. Я пытался найти информацию об это, но не совсем понимаю, что именно искать. В общем если кто-нибудь знает, каким образом это делается, буду благодарен. Желательно на discord.py. Мне не нужен готовый код, а метод, которым это делается.

[image: Вот так это выглядит]

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, amount = 1):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount);
    await ctx.send("Проверка")
```

Где amount = количество удаляемых сообщений сверху